# Getting wrong MAC address of Nexus 6P in app code

Tags: java, android

Right now I'm developing an application that uses WiFi Mac address. When I test app with my Nexus 6P, it displays wrong MAC address and when I checked with another Android device, it shows correct. So what is the problem?

Here's my code

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String mac = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id

Comment: thnxxx @CommonsWare .. My problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device running Marshmallow (API 23 or above) then you can not get the mac address of the device. This security feature has been added starting Marshmallow, hence it returns some constant value like **02:00:00:00:00:00**.

Refer [Android Marshmallow changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id).